# Cannot have POST Data sent with python module Requests

Tags: python, django, post, http-post, python-requests

I have 2 django server. I want to send some POST data from the server A to server B.

I use this code on server A to send data (I simply follow the [tutorial](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/) ) :

```
payload = {"contenu" : Contenu, "ID" : hashage}
payload_json = json.dumps(payload, separators=(',', ': '))
with open('backend/config.json') as json_data:
    facto = json.load(json_data)
    json_data.close
hostnamefacto = facto["Factory"]["IP"]
portFacto = facto["Factory"]["port"]
reponse = requests.post('http://'+hostnamefacto+':'+portFacto+'/outil/test/', data = payload_json)
```

On server B, I use this code to get data :

```
try:
    contenu = request.POST['contenu']
except KeyError:
    contenu = None
try:
    ID = request.POST['ID']
except KeyError:
    ID = None
```

But ID and contenu are equal None. Does someone have an idea of how to do it ?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reading the [POST parameters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response#django.http.HttpRequest.POST)  where you want the raw body parsed as JSON:

```
data = json.loads(request.body)
id = data['ID']
```

---

Let the requests library do the JSON encoding for you:

```
payload = {"contenu" : Contenu, "ID" : hashage}
r = requests.post('http://'+hostnamefacto+':'+portFacto+'/outil/test/', json=paylod)
```

Comment: I try what you told me, but I get an error. I solved it by replace json.load by json.loads and it works. Thank you.

Comment: Doh! those dang typos =)